# Trying to implement HTTPS on selected pages which are making POST request

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ssl, https, http-post

I am trying to implement HTTPS on selected pages which are making POST request in my rails 3.1 project. But not have any success after trying all kind of gems `ssl_requirement`,`rack-ssl-enforcer`. All the gems are helping in making GET request as HTTPS but not have any success for POST request.

Can anybody please help me with this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the solution used `rack-ssl-enforcer` and put these lines in my application.rb file which make it worked

```
 config.middleware.use Rack::SslEnforcer, :only => [%r{^/users/}], :mixed => true
```

Comment: thankx @TaimoorChangaiz i am using the same gem as I have mentioned in my answer...

Comment: :) but friend you missed the gem url